# How do I escape the "return" function in a bash script

Tags: mysql, bash, shell

The script below is loading in a bunch of csv files into a mysql db. I am trying to execute this function within the loop but the mysql table field called return is causing the script to think it should execute the function return.

The ` around return is to escape it for mysql, its a mysql keyword.

```
for f in *.txt; 
do 
 mysql -uroot -ppassword -e "LOAD DATA INFILE '$f' INTO TABLE info FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' LINES TERMINATED BY '\n' (`return`,`id`,`field1`,`field2`);"; 
done
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

it's the stupid quoting convention in mysql of using backtick characters. Can you use Single-quotes instead, ie `'`, ie `'return'`?

Backticks mean "perform command substitution in this current command in the shell", so it is trying to run the command `return`.

If you can't use `'return'` then you can escape ALL of the backticks, like

```
\`return\`
```

IHTH

Comment: Single quotes converts the column names into strings — not the required behaviour.

Answer (score 3):

This happen because strings enclosed by ` ` are executed by bash.

Try this:

```
echo '` date `' # this output the string ` date `
echo "` date `" # this output current time
```

But you cannot change double quotes with single one, because you need `$f` to be sostituded with variable. So escape backtick with `\`.

Comment: You need to use double quotes to get delimited identifiers, don't you?  They're certainly not simply string values which single quotes would imply.

Answer (score 2):

Simply escape your backticks:

```
 mysql -uroot -ppassword -e "LOAD DATA INFILE '$f' INTO TABLE info FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' LINES TERMINATED BY '\n' (\`return\`,\`id\`,\`field1\`,\`field2\`);";
```